# Executing actions multi/single threaded depending on their properties

Tags: c#, multithreading

Given a list of actions that *can* run in parallel, I want to take into account, that one or another action doesn't want to be executed in parallel with other actions (determined by a property of the action).

Consider this simplification:

```
private static Random random;

static void Main (string[] args)
{
  random = new Random();
  new Thread (() => DoSomething (false)).Start();
  new Thread (() => DoSomething (false)).Start();
  new Thread (() => DoSomething (true)).Start();
  new Thread (() => DoSomething (false)).Start();
  new Thread (() => DoSomething (false)).Start();
  Console.Read();

}

private static void DoSomething(bool singlethread)
{
  Console.WriteLine ("Entering " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  if (singlethread)
    Console.WriteLine ("Im the only one!!!");
  Thread.Sleep (random.Next (1000, 5000));
  Console.WriteLine ("Exiting " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

How can I synchronize the actions, so that action 3 waits for action 1 & 2 to exit and then blocks action 4 and 5 ?

## Update

This is what I came up with help of Rob:

```
public class Lock : IDisposable
{
  private static readonly object _object = new object();
  private static readonly AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent (false);
  private static int _count;

  public static IDisposable Get (bool exclusive)
  {
    return new Lock (exclusive);
  }

  private readonly bool _wasTaken;

  private Lock (bool exclusive)
  {
    if (exclusive)
    {
      Monitor.Enter (_object, ref _wasTaken);
      _count++;

      while (_count > 1)
        _event.WaitOne();
    }
    else
    {
      lock (_object)
        Interlocked.Increment (ref _count);
    }
  }

  public void Dispose ()
  {
    Interlocked.Decrement (ref _count);
    if (_wasTaken)
      Monitor.Exit (_object);
    _event.Set();
  }
}
```

Which is used like so:

```
using (Lock.Get(exclusive: false/true)
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Use .join: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could use signals here Auto-/Manual-ResetEvent. But i would advise you to have a look at the TPL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Currently, I'm using the TPL, but I also live with the fact, that all actions are executed in parallel. Now I want to consider, that a action wants to run while no other action is executed... How can the TPL solve this?

Comment: Have you looked at Async/Await and the `Task<T>` class?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Thread` you can start a `Task` on a special scheduler, called the [ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows you to declare tasks to be either concurrency-ready or exclusive.

It works the same as having a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and having the concurrency-ready work-items take the read lock while having the exclusive items take the write lock.

If I understand your case correctly this should fulfill your needs and remove the need for all the manual synchronization code that has been posted in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common mental block, the solution is trivial.  Your requirement is to execute methods A, B and C sequentially.  So let's assume you start a thread to execute A and you put all the locking in place to ensure that another thread doesn't execute B until A is completed.

What you are overlooking is what the thread that executed A is going to do after A is completed.  Shooting off the hip, you'd probably say that you'll allow it to terminate, that thread's job is done.  You started it to execute A, all you needed it for.  Your locking design is going to ensure that another thread executes B at the right time.

But, wait, you already have a perfectly good candidate to execute B.  The thread that executed A.  You are not using it for anything else.  So just give that job to the same thread.  Massive advantage, you don't need any locking at all to ensure that this thread executes B at the right time:

```
void DoWork(object state) {
    A();
    B();
    C();
    ItIsReallyDone.Set();
}
```

Easy, peasy.

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but I can't see how it maps onto Matthias's question. What would his `DoSomething` method look like under your scheme?  Or are you saying that his whole approach is flawed?

Answer (score 2):

Based on usr's suggestion, here is another implementation that works without manual synchronisation.

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    private static readonly ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair TaskSchedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();

    static void Main()
    {
        DoSomething(false);
        DoSomething(false);
        DoSomething(true);
        DoSomething(false);
        DoSomething(false);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void DoSomething(bool singleThread)
    {
        var scheduler = singleThread ? TaskSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler : TaskSchedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (singleThread)
                Console.WriteLine("Starting exclusive task.");
            DoSomething();
        }, new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, scheduler)
            .ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                if (singleThread)
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished exclusive task.");
            });
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting task on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(Random.Next(1000, 5000));
        Console.WriteLine("Finished task on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.  You can use a reference count.

I've tested this in the console a few times, and it seems like it's doing the right thing.

```
class Program
{
    private static Random random;
    private static int refCount;
    private static object syncObject = new object();
    private static AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        random = new Random();
        new Thread(() => DoSomething(false)).Start();
        new Thread(() => DoSomething(false)).Start();
        new Thread(() => DoSomething(true)).Start();
        new Thread(() => DoSomething(false)).Start();
        new Thread(() => DoSomething(false)).Start();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void DoSomething(bool singleThread)
    {
        if (singleThread)
        {
            lock (syncObject)
            {
                ++refCount;
                // Inside this lock, no new thread can get to the parameterless DoSomething() method.  
                // However, existing threads can continue to do their work, and notify this thread that they have finished by signalling using the resetEvent.
                while (refCount > 1)
                    resetEvent.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Starting exclusive task.");
                DoSomething();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished exclusive task.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lock (syncObject)
                ++refCount;

            DoSomething();
        }

        --refCount;
        resetEvent.Set();
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting task on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished task on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good for now :) Why do you use a lock for the `Interlocked.Increment` statement?

Comment: Interlocked.[In,De]crement() is actually belt and braces.  But the lock is necessary so that other threads block while a singleThreaded method is executing.

Comment: I think there's a flaw. Suppose, two singlethread actions pass the increment step... both will wait forever.

Comment: Please edit your code according to my update. I tested it, but I will wait for more responses, as I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Done. That's collaborative coding for you.

Comment: By the way, I also changed the initial state of the event, so that a single-threaded execution can proceed if it is the first thread to go through. I love threading problems (This feels like the right solution -- I've learned to trust that sensation over the years).